# Python: Sort an array

Tags: python

I have a class that's sole purpose is to sort an array that's given as a parameter, however first of all, I'm getting an error "int not iterable." My question is what is this error and am I doing my sorting correctly?  Thanks.  Here is my sorter class being called by the other class below.

```
class Sorter:
    def reverseWackySort(self, vals):
        i = 0
        j = 0
        temp = 0
        length = len(vals)
        for i in length:
            for j in (length -1):
                if vals[j] > vals[j+1]:
                    temp = vals[j]
                    vals[j] = vals[j+1]
                    vals[j+1] = temp;
        return vals
```

Code -

```
from Sorter import Sorter

def TestSorter():
    rws = Sorter()


    nums = [88, 1, 7, 32, 18, 77, 34, 99, 54, 22]

    print "\nBefore Sort: ", nums

    rws.reverseWackySort(nums)

    print "After Sort:   {}\n".format(nums)

TestSorter()
```

Comment: Why are you using a class in the first place? What is a `Sorter` instance for? This isn't Java, where you have to make every function a method… More importantly, do you have any reason to believe the class is relevant to the problem? If not, given that explaining it takes up half your text, and the implementation causes an `IndentationError`, and it draws more attention than your actual problem… maybe it would be better to trim things down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Is there a particularly good reason why you aren't using [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)?

Comment: It's homework actually, practicing not using built-in methods :)

Comment: @Binka: That is a perfectly acceptable reason! Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over an integer:

```
for i in length:
    for j in (length -1):
```

Perhaps you wanted to iterate over the *range* instead:

```
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length -1):
```

[`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) produces a sequence of integers up to (but not including) `length` for you.

Note that you can swap variables in place in Python without a temporary intermediary:

```
vals[j], vals[j+1] = vals[j+1], vals[j]
```

and you don't need to 'pre-declare' variables either; the `i = 0`, `j = 0` and `temp = 0` lines are redundant.

Comment: Thank you.  That was my problem :)

Comment: Done, I have a quick question if you don't mind.  I fixed it to sort by decreasing order instead.  Now that my list is sorted.  I have to try and sort it in this pattern.  "largest -> smallest -> next largest -> next smallest ->" etc.  Any ideas?  For example, in the other direction in Java, I was able to do this

Comment: @Binka: You should open a new question for that.

Comment: @Binka: It's impossible to format code in questions. In this case, as John Y says, you should open a new question. When that isn't appropriate, sometimes editing your existing question is. When neither is appropriate, just post it somewhere like http://pastebin.com, and put a link here.

Comment: @Binka: But one quick hint: The easiest way to do it is to figure out how to build that structure out of an already-sorted list. Then you can just use your existing sort function, then that new function.

Comment: Thanks, if you read through the comment in here http://pastebin.com/Tk0A8rHN   You should see what I'm asking.  I'd really appreciate help :)